# Scheme null? statement

Tags: lambda, null, scheme, conditional-statements

Im quite new to the Scheme programming language and I just can't figure out the difference between these two pieces of code, particularly the lines I have indicated.

```
;program that returns the Nth element in a list where N is an integer argument

(define getElement
(lambda (N L)
(cond
  ((null? L) '() )
  ((= N 1) (car L))
  (#t(getElement (- N 1) (cdr L)));this line
)
)
)

;takes a list L and a number N and returns the list L but with the first N elements removed
(define remove
(lambda (N L)
(cond
  ((null? L) '() )
  ((= N 0) L)
  (#t(remove (- N 1) (cdr L)));and this line
)
)
)
```

Why is the output of these programs so different? I can't see what impact the 2 lines after the condition statement has on the output of the programs other than checking if the list is empty and if the integer N is a certain value, do this.

This is my first post so any advice is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say,

> if the integer N is a certain value, do this

and the difference is in the "do this".

The first one,

```
((= N 1) (car L))
```

says "to get the first element of a list, take the `car` of the list".

The second one,

```
((= N 0) L)
```

says "to remove no elements from a list, return the entire list".

The recursions *look* exactly the same, but the first one reads "get element `N - 1` from the `cdr` of the list", while the second reads "remove `N - 1` elements from the `cdr` of the list".

(It looks like the first function has been translated from Lisp, where `nil` is "false-y". A more Scheme-y function would return `#f`.)

Answer (score 2):

Both functions are recursive and use the same recursion strategy.  However, they do very different things  when you get to the bottom of the recursion.

Each function reduces n by one and reduces the list by one element, calling itself in the new context.
So, the list (at least as represented within the arguments to the functions) keeps getting shorter in both cases.
The remove function returns the entire remaining list.  Since a number of elements have already been removed from the copy of the list in the remove function's argument, this has the effect of returning a shortened list.
However, the nth-element function doesn't return the list; it returns (car l), or returns the element in the cons cell contained in l.  That is, it only returns the current element of the list.
That is why they produce different results.

Answer (score 0):

The lines you have indicated does the same. **Absolutely no difference!** It recurses to itself with the index reduced and the list changed to the `cdr`.

When the base case hits the first returns the first element and the second return the list.

```
(getElement 1 '(1 2 3)) ; ==> 1, Since it does (car L)
(remove 0 '(1 2 3))     ; ==> (1 2 3), since it does L
```

Now if your `getElement` worked like `list-ref` `0` should have been the base case, the same as `remove`. Also it should signal an error when the list is empty before the index is zero. This is more like it:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs))
(define (my-list-ref lst pos)
  (cond ((null? lst) (raise 'list-too-short))
        ((zero? pos) (car lst))
        (else (my-list-ref (cdr lst) (- pos 1)))))

(my-list-ref '() 1)
; ==> uncaught exception: list-too-short
```